# Call js function after rendering Angular directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, combobox, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a quick Angular directive that will generate combo-boxes using a jQuery UI extension I've found.

The extension is quite simple.  I just need to create a standard select element and then run the function "combobox()" on it.  I'm not sure where to do this in my angular directive though.

partials/elements/combobox.html

```
<select class="dropdown" ng-options="option as option for option in selectOptions" ng-model="selectModel" />
```

app-directives.js

```
appDirectives.directive('combobox', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'partials/elements/combobox.html',
        scope: {
            selectModel: "=model",
            selectOptions: "=options"
        }
    };
});
```

in my view

```
<combobox model="query.favouriteFruit" options="fruits"></combobox>
```

I'm not sure where I should be putting in my call to .combobox().  I tried doing this:

```
$(function() { $("combobox select").combobox(); });
```

But of course this doesn't work as the directive has not rendered in time.  Is there a way to call it only when the directive is done rendering?

Thanks for your time,
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle that logic in the link function of the directive.

```
appDirectives.directive('combobox', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'partials/elements/combobox.html',
        scope: {
            selectModel: "=model",
            selectOptions: "=options"
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // wait till the initial digest cycle is triggered. 
            $timeout(function () {
                // change the select to combobox
                element.combobox(); 
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Vinay, you are a shiny golden god! This looks to be exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: That sounds really nice. Thanks. Good luck.